# Render a select based on another one in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, select, dynamic

I'm trying to render a select component with the options base on this one

```
<select name="regions" id="regions" onChange={(e) => {}}>
          {regions.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <option key={index} value={index}>
                {item.name}
              </option>
            );
          })}
        </select>
```

This is regions:

```
const italianRegions = [
    {
      name: "Abruzzo",
      slug: "abruzzo",
      province: [
        { name: "L'Aquila", abbreviato: "AQ", slug: "laquila" },
        { name: "Teramo", abbreviato: "TE", slug: "teramo" },
        { name: "Pescara", abbreviato: "PE", slug: "pescara" },
        { name: "Chieti", abbreviato: "CH", slug: "chieti" },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "Basilicata",
      slug: "basilicata",
      province: [
        { name: "Potenza", abbreviato: "PZ", slug: "potenza" },
        { name: "Matera", abbreviato: "MT", slug: "matera" },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "Calabria",
      slug: "calabria",
      province: [
        { name: "Catanzaro", abbreviato: "CZ", slug: "catanzaro" },
        { name: "Cosenza", abbreviato: "CS", slug: "cosenza" },
        { name: "Reggio Calabria", abbreviato: "RC", slug: "reggio-calabria" },
        { name: "Crotone", abbreviato: "KR", slug: "crotone" },
        { name: "Vibo Valentia", abbreviato: "VV", slug: "vibo-valentia" },
      ],
    }
...
```

In the other select I want only the "province" of the selected object.
I can't figure it out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a state to know which region is currently selected, and then use that region to get the list of provinces.

```js
const [selectedRegion, setSelectedRegion] = useState()

return (
  <>
    <select value={selectedRegion} onChange={(e) => {setSelectedRegion(e.target.value}}>
      {regions.map((item, index) => (
        <option key={item.name} value={item.name}>
          {item.name}
        </option>
      )}
    </select>
    <select>
      {regions.find((r) => r.name === selectedRegion).province.map((item, index) => (
        <option key={item.name} value={item.name}>
          {item.name}
        </option>
      )}
    </select>
  </>
)
```